# store params in database using ngclick via angularjs ,php,mysql

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs

**index.html**

```
<html>
<body>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<body ng-controller="personController">
    <button ng-click="addNewClicked=!addNewClicked;" >Add New        person</button>
    <form ng-init="addNewClicked=false; " ng-if="addNewClicked" id="newPersonForm" >
       <input type="text"  ng-model="input.firstname" placeholder="Add New   firstname" ng-focus="addNewClicked">{{input.firstname}}
       <input type="text"  ng-model="input.lastname" placeholder="Add New last name" ng-focus="addNewClicked">{{input.lastname}}
       <button  type="submit" ng-click="addPerson(input)">Add New person</button>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

**app.js**

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('personController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.addPerson = function (input) {
    $http.post("ajax/addPerson.php?     firstname="+firstname+"$lastname="+lastname).success(function(data){
    });
  };
  });
```

**addPerson.php**

```
 <?php 
 require_once '../includes/db.php'; // The mysql database connection     script
 if(isset($_GET['firstname'])){
 $firstname = $_GET['firstname'];
 $lastname=$_GET['lastname'];



 $query="INSERT INTO persons(firstname,lastname)  VALUES    ('$firstname','$lastname')";
  $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

 $result = $mysqli->affected_rows;

  echo $json_response = json_encode($result);
  }
  ?>
```

**db.php**

```
 <?php 
 $DB_HOST = '127.0.0.1';
 $DB_USER = 'root';
 $DB_PASS = '';
 $DB_NAME = 'angularcode_person';
 $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
 ?>
```

As a beginner i don't know how to store the parameters into the database.i want to store the parameters firstname and lastname into the database .for that usining an ng-click function addperson().

Comment: Please be more specific. What errors are you having? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing the problem you are having i can only guess.

Instead of sending the input values through the function you can use [`$scope`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) in your angular controller.

To be able to access firstname and lastname values you have to change the model names from `input.firstname` and `input.lastname` to just `firstname` and `lastname`

Remove the `input` argument in `ng-click="addPerson(input)"`

Then, in your javascript file change the function to use `$scope`, like this:

```
$scope.addPerson = function () {
  $http.post("ajax/addPerson.php?firstname="+$scope.firstname+"&lastname="+$scope.lastname).success(function(data){
    console.log("Success")
  });
};
```